# JSF Maven Project MVC Implementation and DataTables

Tags: java, maven, jsf

How to connect the Service bean class and Controller bean class so that I can call the method bound to a button from the controller class.

I have coded the model classes for Login and Employee. Similarly I have Service classes for both of them and Controller classes as well.

If required, I would also provide a snippet code for more help.

Comment: As you mention, please post the code you have been working on, just update your existing question, dont post it as an answer or new question. Thanks

Comment: There's an <pre>EmployeeModel</pre> class having private variables like id, name, department and company. There are other two classes <pre>EmployeeController</pre> and <pre>EmployeeService</pre>. Getter and setter methods have already been defined in the Model class